# Don't show login popup in admin panel when user is logged out

Tags: wordpress

I've changed wordpress admin look, and now have an issue with this, when I am logged out as usual in admin panel we see popup of login page and it's not good because it has horizontal scroll(no responsive part). I want immediately redirect to login page and don't show login popup.